# People Picker control stopped working

Tags: people-picker

I have a form designed in InfoPath which was working correctly containing a number of people pickers for traveller and preparer details.
I was playing around amending the form in SharePoint designer, looking to allow multiple entries in the traveller field.
Cut a long story short, I didn't want the changes, closed the form (but may have saved it) and now when I try and submit the original form, it comes up with an error 
***"The form cannot be submitted.
The form cannot be submitted to the specified SharePoint list or document library. The SharePoint location may be read-only or you may not have permissions to access it."***
The form works perfectly if the traveller people picker is left blank.
The preparer people picker works fine.
Anyone help at all?

Comment: Could it be that you accidentally marked a field as “Enforce unique values” in the InfoPath form while playing around?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it - I had inadvertently restricted the selection from a specific SharePoint group instead of allowing all users!